# How can I put inline perl code in html, like php?

Tags: html, perl

Do not you know a method to carry out the following code like php?

```
<html>
<?perl
print( 'test' );
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

using [HTML::Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/):

```
<%perl>
use Date::Calc;
my @today  = Date::Calc->Today();
my $str = "$today[0]-$today[1]-$today[2]";
</%perl>

<html>
<body>
Today is <%$str %>
</body></html>
```

Apache Config:

```
PerlModule HTML::Mason::ApacheHandler
<Location /usr/local/apache/htdocs/mason>
SetHandler perl-script
PerlHandler HTML::Mason::ApacheHandler
</Location>
```

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is a little different, but that's the approach used by [HTML::Mason](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Mason).

Personally, I prefer a templating system that encourages more separation of code and presentation.  [Template Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template) does that while allowing flexibility to do just about anything you'd ever want to do.

Comment: At my last job the major product we worked on used Mason AND Template Toolkit. Figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

There's also EmbPerl though it is not too widely used.

Answer (score 2):

While you can embed Perl directly into a [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) file:

```
[% PERL %]
use Date::Calc;
my @today  = Date::Calc->Today();
my $str = "$today[0]-$today[1]-$today[2]";
[% END %]

<html>
<body>
Today is [% $str %]
</body></html>
```

A better way is to use a [Plugin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Plugin::Date):

```
[% USE date %]
<html>
<body>
Today is [% date.format(date.now, format = '%d-%b-%Y') %]
</body></html>
```